# Class has No Initializers Error Realm Class Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I'm getting a Class has no initializers Error. Is this not how I would set up the class. This is for a Realm OBject Database, the Properties I want to store. I'm new to swift and realm, but I figured this is how it would be done. If I take out the init() function and just assign everything values it works, however properties like justTook and all that I don't want start with a value, I need to set it later in the program.

Here is my code:

```
class MedInfo: Object {
    //  Info To Be Stored
    @objc dynamic var keyID = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var medName: String
    @objc dynamic var medDose: String
    @objc dynamic var currentDate: Date
    @objc dynamic var timeTook: Date
    @objc dynamic var lastTook: Date
    @objc dynamic var durationOfTime: Date
    @objc dynamic var doctorName: String
    @objc dynamic var rxDate: Date
    @objc dynamic var medInfo: String
    @objc dynamic var pictureOfMed: UIImage

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "keyID"
    }

    convenience init(medName: String, medDose: String, currentDate: Date, timeTook: Date, lastTook: Date, durationOfTime: Date, doctorName: String,rxDate: Date, medInfo: String, pictureOfMed: UIImage) {
        self.medName = medName
        self.medDose = medDose
        self.currentDate = currentDate
        self.timeTook = timeTook
        self.lastTook = lastTook
        self.durationOfTime = durationOfTime
        self.doctorName = doctorName
        self.rxDate = rxDate
        self.medInfo = medInfo
        self.pictureOfMed = pictureOfMed
    }
```

Comment: you can declare variables as optionals if you don't want to give them a value during initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set default values for all parameters, as vaguely described in the docs. From [here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models):

> When using Realm from Swift, the Swift.reflect(_:) function is used to
>   determine information about your models, which requires that calling
>   init() succeed. **This means that all non-optional properties must have
>   a default value.**

All the examples show this, so follow them. Your class should thus be declared:

```
class MedInfo: Object {
    //  Info To Be Stored
    @objc dynamic var keyID = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var medName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var medDose: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var currentDate: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var timeTook: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var lastTook: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var durationOfTime: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var doctorName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var rxDate: Date = Date()
    @objc dynamic var medInfo: String = ""

    // UIImage not supported, you'll need to store a URL/filename or something else
    @objc dynamic var pictureOfMed: UIImage
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call the init to create the instance.

```
convenience init(medName: String, medDose: String, currentDate: Date, timeTook: Date, lastTook: Date, durationOfTime: Date, doctorName: String,rxDate: Date, medInfo: String, pictureOfMed: UIImage) {

    self.init() 

    self.medName = medName
    self.medDose = medDose
    self.currentDate = currentDate
    self.timeTook = timeTook
    self.lastTook = lastTook
    self.durationOfTime = durationOfTime
    self.doctorName = doctorName
    self.rxDate = rxDate
    self.medInfo = medInfo
    self.pictureOfMed = pictureOfMed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ces already correctly quoted from the Realm documentation: "**This means that all non-optional properties must have a default value.**"

This is why I think the best way for you to create your Realm object is to declare your variables as optionals.

This way you will not have to call init. This is the way I create my own Realm objects and the way I've seen most people create them.

So your object would look like this:

```
class MedInfo: Object {
//  Info To Be Stored
@objc dynamic var keyID = UUID().uuidString
@objc dynamic var medName: String?
@objc dynamic var medDose: String?
@objc dynamic var currentDate: Date?
@objc dynamic var timeTook: Date?
@objc dynamic var lastTook: Date?
@objc dynamic var durationOfTime: Date?
@objc dynamic var doctorName: String?
@objc dynamic var rxDate: Date?
@objc dynamic var medInfo: String?
@objc dynamic var pictureOfMed: UIImage?

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "keyID"
}
```

Comment: You can indeed do this. But by making your model properties optional, your model properties are now _optional_. Yes, I know what I said there. But now, accessing model properties you will have to deal with the possibility of them being nil. This is ok if they _can_ be nil, but you should **not** make them optional if doing so weakens the model. In the example, I can see that maybe pictureOfMed would be optional (String), but would it make sense for all the other fields to be nil?

Comment: @ces Well you're right of course that working with non-optionals is safer. But as the OP said that when he "just assign everything values it works, however properties like justTook and all that I don't want start with a value". So that's why I think that in this case working with optionals is more suitable. He specifically said that he would not like to start with default values. Of course he has to calculate the risk of nil values into his code. Your answer is still good though imo.